# Learn Probability and Permutation and combination

Tags: probability, learning

I am very weak in solving problem related to probability and permutation and combination. Can you please guide me the good content by which I can understand it better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is to vague to get a useful answer.

Comment: Zerotoinfinite--would you ask your question again with more specifics? What kinds of problems do you have to do, and what trouble do you have with them? Counting objects, or finite probabilities? What grade are you in? That kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You learn to swim by swimming, learn to talk by talking and **you learn combinatorics by solving problems.**

You can get problems at [**Art of Problem Solving**](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/), try to solve as many "different" problems as you can.

If you need help you know [**where to get it**](https://math.stackexchange.com/) ;)

May the force be with you!